# How to match two equal string with IF statement in python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

My Python code:

```
import re

output = "your test contains errors"    

match2 = re.findall('(.* contains errors)',output)
mat2 = "['your test contains errors'] "

if match2 == mat2:
    print "PASS"
```

In the above python program, I have string in 'match2' and mat2. If it's same it should print PASS.

I am not getting any error if I run this program. If I print "match2" and "mat2" is giving the same equal output. but if I use "if match2 == mat2" is not printing as 'PASS'.

Can anyone please help me to fix this.

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,

Kumar.

Comment: As a general rule of debugging, always try printing or checking your returned values in interactive or interpreter mode. This helps avoid headaches with trivial problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a list, not a string. So `mat2` should be a list, too:

```
mat2 = ['your test contains errors']
```

If you want to check `your test contains errors` in the string, you can use `in` operator:

```
if "your test contains errors" in output:
    print "PASS"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing for a string match you should compare strings and using re.search is sufficient:

```
output = "your test contains errors"

match2 = re.search('(.* contains errors)',output)
mat2 = 'your test contains errors'
if match2 and match.group() == mat2:
    print "PASS"
```

`findall` will also return multiple matches so even using `mat2 = ['your test contains errors']` would fail if there were multiple matches.

Your regex approach does not actually make sense, if you are comparing both strings for equality which based on *In the above python program, I have string in 'match2' and mat2. If it's same it should print PASS.* you are, then you should not be using a regex at all:

```
output = "your test contains errors"     
mat2 = 'your test contains errors'

if output == mat2:
    print "PASS"
```

You regex is equivalent to `str.startswith` so a simple:

```
if output.startswith(mat2):
    print "PASS"
```

will do the same.

Your regex approach will match substrings:

```
import re

output = "foo your test contains errors"

match2 = re.findall('(.* contains errors)',output)

print(match2)
```

Outputs:

```
 ['foo your test contains errors']
```

So the only way you will get a match using your regex is if the string starts with `your test ...` which `str.startswith` can test without any need for  a regex.

So if you want to find if the string starts with `'your test contains errors'` use `str.startswith` if you only want to find if `contains errors` is in the string use `if "contains errors" in output` or the equivalent is using `if match2:` using search as that will find if `"contains errors"` is in your string preceded by any characters.

You could also use `if 'your test contains errors'` to find if the substring is anywhere in your string but that is not what your regex is doing.

Comment: @falsetru, you can use group to check against mat2 but the regex makes no sense at all as the OP is checking for an exact match

Comment: Thanks for your answer. its makes sense. Thanks.